# extend the CRUD method in LoopBack

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I would like to know how to extend CRUD methods created by LoopBack.

I have a model with an attribute `public_key`. I would like to build two custom behaviors for the `POST` api endpoint for this model.

1. generate a public key and set the value
2. generate a private key and send it back as a result (using SSL)

How can I extend the default method to implement these behaviors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to override the default method by creating a javascript file under `server/boot`.

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var MyModel = app.models.MyModel;
  var create = MyModel.create;

  // Overrides POST '/api/MyModel' endpoint
  MyModel.create = function(data, done) {
    // Do custom things

    create.call(MyModel, data, done);
  };
};
```

However I was not able to modify the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom [remote methods](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods) that are exposed as REST endpoints